# Tkinter - UI gets broken when draw a big scrollable canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a text clustering app and there's a screen showing all the clusters. I've learned to make scrollable lists of widgets from other questions. Each cluster is scrollable and the whole grid is also scrollable. When the app works, it looks like this:
[image: screenshot the app when things go well]

When users adjust the slider, the clusters are updated, all the scrollable lists are destroyed and new clusters are drawn. However, after 3 or 4 times adjusting the slider, the UI gets broken and being drawn all over my desktop screen. Please let me know if I've missed something?
[image]

Here's the class for scrolling, other views just extend this class:

```
from typing import List
import platform
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tksheet._tksheet_vars import *



class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, bg="white", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, bg=bg, borderwidth=0,  **kwargs) 

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg=bg, borderwidth=0)
        self.viewPort = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg=bg, borderwidth=0)

        
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)                     
        self.canvas_window = self.canvas.create_window(
                (0,0),
                window=self.viewPort, anchor="nw",tags="self.viewPort")

        self.viewPort.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)                      
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)                       
            
        self.viewPort.bind('<Enter>', self.onEnter)                                 
        self.viewPort.bind('<Leave>', self.onLeave)                                 

        self.onFrameConfigure(None)

    def destroy(self):
        self.canvas.delete("alll")
        super().destroy()
        # self.destroy()

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))                

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_window, width = canvas_width)           

    def onMouseWheel(self, event):
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1* (event.delta/120)), "units")
        elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * event.delta), "units")
        else:
            if event.num == 4:
                self.canvas.yview_scroll( -1, "units" )
            elif event.num == 5:
                self.canvas.yview_scroll( 1, "units" )
    
    def onEnter(self, event):
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            self.canvas.bind_all("<Button-4>", self.onMouseWheel)
            self.canvas.bind_all("<Button-5>", self.onMouseWheel)
        else:
            self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.onMouseWheel)

    def onLeave(self, event):
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            self.canvas.unbind_all("<Button-4>")
            self.canvas.unbind_all("<Button-5>")
        else:
            self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    def scroll_to(self, fraction=1):
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(fraction)
```

Here're classes for each text item and clusters:

```
class TextItem(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(
            self,
            master,
            idx:int,
            text:str,
            selectable = False,
            selected=True,
            bg="white",
            on_item_selected=None,
            **kwds
        ):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg=bg, borderwidth=0, **kwds)
            self.__text = text
            self.__select_var = tk.BooleanVar()
            self.__select_var.set(selected)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

            if selectable:
                self.check = tk.Checkbutton(
                        self,
                        anchor='e',
                        text=self.__text,
                        variable=self.__select_var,
                        bg=bg,
                        fg=theme_light_blue["header_fg"],
                        command=on_item_selected
                    )
                self.check.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
            else:
                self.idx = tk.Label(
                    self,
                    text=str(idx),
                    bg=bg,
                    fg="#728494"
                ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
                self.check = tk.Label(
                        self,
                        anchor='e',
                        text=self.__text,
                        bg=bg,
                        fg=theme_light_blue["header_fg"]
                    )
                self.check.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
    
    @property
    def is_selected(self):
        return self.__select_var.get()


class Cluster():
    def __init__(self, id:int, samples: List[str],) -> None:
        self.__samples = samples
        self.__id = id

    @property
    def samples(self):
        return self.__samples
    
    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id


class ClusterFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(
        self,
        root,
        cluster: Cluster,
        bg="white",
        selectable=False,
        selecteds=None,
        title=None,
        **kwds
        ):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, bg=bg, **kwds)
            self.__wrapper = tk.Frame(
                self,
                highlightbackground = theme_light_blue["index_border_fg"],
                highlightthickness=0.5, bg=bg
            )
            self.__selectable = selectable
            self.__cluster = cluster
            if not title:
                title = f"Cluster {cluster.id}: { len(cluster.samples)} samples"
            self.__title_label = tk.Label(self.__wrapper, text = title)
            self.__title_label.pack(side="top", fill="both")
            if self.__selectable:
                self.__selection_status = tk.Label(self.__wrapper, text = "Selected: ")
                self.__selection_status.pack(side="top", fill="both")


            self.scrollFrame = ScrollFrame(self.__wrapper)
            if not selecteds:
                selecteds = [True] * len(cluster.samples)
            # self.__selected_count = selecteds.sum()
            self.__view_items = []
            for idx, sample in enumerate(cluster.samples):
                item = TextItem(
                    self.scrollFrame.viewPort,
                    idx + 1,
                    sample,
                    selected=selecteds[idx],
                    selectable=self.__selectable,
                    on_item_selected=self.update_selected_status
                )
                item.grid(row=idx, column=0, sticky='w', padx=1, pady=1)
                self.__view_items.append(item)

            self.scrollFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            self.__wrapper.pack( fill="both", expand=True)
            if self.__selectable:
                self.update_selected_status()
    
    def get_selected_samples(self):
        return [self.__cluster.samples[idx] for idx, item in enumerate(self.__view_items) if item.is_selected]
    
    def update_selected_status(self):
        selected_count = len(self.get_selected_samples())
        self.__selection_status.config(text=f"Selected: {selected_count}")
    
    def scroll_to(self, fraction=1):
        self.scrollFrame.scroll_to(fraction)
```

Here's the code for the grid view.

class ClusterGrid(tk.Frame):
def **init**(self, root,  clusters, num_cols=3, **kwargs):
super().**init**(root, bg="white", **kwargs)

```
    # main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    self.__num_cols = num_cols
    self.__clusters = clusters
    
    self.__main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0)
    self.__main_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    main_scrbar = ttk.Scrollbar(
        self, 
        orient=tk.VERTICAL, 
        command=self.__main_canvas.yview
    )
    main_scrbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

    self.__main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=main_scrbar.set)
    # self.main_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox("all")))


    self.__scroll_frame = tk.Frame(self.__main_canvas, bg="white")
    self.__canvas_window = self.__main_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.__scroll_frame, anchor="nw")

    self.__scroll_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)                      
    self.__main_canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)                       
        
    self.__scroll_frame.bind('<Enter>', self.onEnter)                                 
    self.__scroll_frame.bind('<Leave>', self.onLeave)

    for i, intent in enumerate(self.__clusters[:30]):
        col = i % self.__num_cols
        row = int(i/self.__num_cols)
        sc = ClusterFrame(self.__scroll_frame, intent, selectable=True)
        sc.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5)

    self.onFrameConfigure(None)

def destroy(self):
    self.__main_canvas.delete("all")
    super().destroy()


def onFrameConfigure(self, event):    
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    # print("ScrollFrame: onFrameConfigure")
    self.__main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.__main_canvas.bbox("all"))   

def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
    '''Reset the canvas window to encompass inner frame when required'''
    # print("ScrollFrame: onCanvasConfigure")
    canvas_width = event.width
    self.__main_canvas.itemconfig(self.__canvas_window, width = canvas_width)   


def onEnter(self, event):
    print("ScrollFrame: onEnter")                                
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
        self.__main_canvas.bind_all("<Button-4>", self.onMouseWheel)
        self.__main_canvas.bind_all("<Button-5>", self.onMouseWheel)
    else:
        self.__main_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.onMouseWheel)


def onMouseWheel(self, event):
    # print("ScrollFrame: onMouseWheel")                            
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        self.__main_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1* (event.delta/120)), "units")
    elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        self.__main_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * event.delta), "units")
    else:
        if event.num == 4:
            self.__main_canvas.yview_scroll( -1, "units" )
        elif event.num == 5:
            self.__main_canvas.yview_scroll( 1, "units" )

def onLeave(self, event):
    print("ScrollFrame: onLeave")                                                  
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
        self.__main_canvas.unbind_all("<Button-4>")
        self.__main_canvas.unbind_all("<Button-5>")
    else:
        self.__main_canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>") 

def destroy(self) -> None:
    # self.__main_canvas.delete("all")
    return super().destroy()
```

Finally the code for inflating the gridview.

```
import random
from threading import Timer
from tkinter import *
from scrollable_frames import ClusterGrid, Cluster



def clear_grid(view):
    print("clear_grid: ", view)
    if not view:
        return
    for widget in view.winfo_children():
        print("widget: ", widget)
        widget.destroy()
    


def on_slider_change(new_val, root):
    global slider_timer
    print("new_val: ", new_val)
    if slider_timer:
        slider_timer.cancel()
        print("cancelled")
    slider_timer = Timer(2, process, args=(new_val, root,))
    slider_timer.start()

def process(val, root):
    global intent_grid
    print("process...", val, intent_grid)
    
    print(val)
    clear_grid(intent_grid)
    clusters = []
    for i in range(100):
        samples = [ f"This is a sample text {i}" for i in range(100)]
        cl = Cluster(i, samples=samples)
        clusters.append(cl)
    intent_grid = ClusterGrid(root, clusters=clusters)
    intent_grid.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew")


root=Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
intent_grid = None

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

slider_timer = None
threshold_slider_val = DoubleVar(value=0.6)
threshold_slider = Scale(
        root,
        from_= 0.3,
        to=1,
        resolution=0.05,
        orient=HORIZONTAL,
        variable=threshold_slider_val,
        command=lambda x: on_slider_change(new_val=x, root=root)
    )
threshold_slider.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I know drawing all elements on the canvas is not cool. Is there any way to just draw what're visible? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: *When users adjust the slider, the clusters are updated, all the scrollable lists are destroyed and new clusters are drawn.* -- isn't it possible to reuse your widgets ?

Comment: Also you use `Timer` which is a blocking call. Your question as written needs to be split into separate questions with [mre]. One needs to write pages to answer this question.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: "isn't it possible to reuse your widgets ?" That's a good point. It's kinda possible but the number of widgets in a scrollable view changes every time. There're widgets needed to be created and destroyed anyways.

Comment: @Thingamabobs "Also you use Timer which is a blocking call": In the code above, sample data is created by a list comprehension (20 elements), so I didn't use a separated thread. I'll edit the question to put a note on that as well. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are making things harder than they need to be. Why not just simply using Listboxes ?

Comment: When u called this from scrollable_frames import ClusterGrid, Cluster. I don't see CLuster.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: I may have to go back to Listbox if I can't get this to work. The reason is Listbox doesn't allow anything other than text, and I want to add a checkbox there as well. I've edited the screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra it's in the second block of code, right after TextItem.